# Create market order on Bybit using CCXT with SL and TP using python?

Tags: python, bots, ccxt, bybit, python-bybit

Does anyone have an example of how to create a market order with take profit and stop loss?

I have been through the docs and because this is the first time i've done anything like this I don't really get it!

I have everything working except for actually placing the order!!

I can't get the stop loss to work, my active market order won't close

```
    symbol = 'BTC/USDT:USDT'
    sl = 20950
    
    params = dict(
        reduce_only = True,            
        leverage=1,
        stop_px = sl)

    order = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='limit', side='sell', amount=0.01, price=21100, params=params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CCXT is currently adding support for `stopLossPrice` and `takeProfitPrice`](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/13822)

You can create an order with a stop loss and take profit tied to the order like

```
exchange.create_order(
    symbol='BTC/USDT:USDT',
    type='limit',
    side='sell',
    amount=0.01,
    price=21100,
    params={
        'leverage': 1,
        'stopLossPrice': 20950,
        'takeProfitPrice': 21950,
    },
)
```

Comment: This gives error "expect Rising, but trigger_price[285500000] \u003c= current[286250000]??1","result":{},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1680156234860}

Answer (score 0):

To identify the side, use the trigger : 'triggerDirection': 1 or 'triggerDirection': 2